# SimplerXMLGenerator has no attribute '_write'

Tags: python, xml, pelican

When I use Pelican to create a static webpage.

`CRITICAL: SimplerXMLGenerator instance has no attribute '_write'`

someone says this function has been removed from django:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/xmlutils.py

really? And how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `_write` comes from the python stdlib `xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator`. Something must be overriding the built-in `xml` library. IIRC, `PyXML` used to do that. Also, not entirely related but pelican uses standalone version of [feedgenerator](https://github.com/dmdm/feedgenerator-py3k)

Comment: @Avaris plz consider to add the comment as an answer. That will remove this question from "unanswered". Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

`_write` comes from the python stdlib `xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator`. Something must be overriding the built-in `xml` library. IIRC, `PyXML` used to do that.

*PS*: Not entirely related but pelican uses standalone version of [feedgenerator](https://github.com/dmdm/feedgenerator-py3k)